# Is there a way to post a link to another file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

In my comments I often reference other files, for example

```
// macro to allow easy access to object title, used in *SomeViewController.m*
```

and I would be really pleased if there was a way to click through that text to get to the specified file (in this case, the SomeViewController.m).

The underlying mechanism is definitely there, as indicated by being able to Apple-click through class names to that class's file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `SomeViewController.m` you can navigate using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + Click if specifying the class name, for example `SomeViewController`.

If the code cannot be modified (i.e. third party code), I've found <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> shortcut to be a real time-saver for File and Object navigation in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing files is not very common in comments. Usually, you want to reference types, e.g. `SomeViewController`. Types, classes, methods can move from file to file during refactoring, that's why you should avoid referencing file names.

Types/Classes/Methods can be easily clicked through in Xcode.

In the example you mention, you don't need a comment saying where it is used. The important part is to say how to use it. Otherwise you will have documentation that is really easy to break - e.g. when the macro is replaced by a function/method by another programmer, file is renamed etc. and the macro comment stays there.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I've saved my coworkers a good bit of goose chasing by using references in my comments (almost always for understanding unexpected workarounds). I didn't realize I could ⌘-click through class names in *comments* though. So thanks.